# Laravel 10 Upload image and get image from storage

Tags: laravel

I've read through many tutorials and it still isn't working. I've added a sym link but it still doesn't save or show the image correctly. Can someone tell me the process of the following:

I want to upload an image to the folder storage/app/profilephotos/. It will be called whatever thhe hasname of the image is.
Then I want to be able to view the image via the url on the website.

to test, I created this sym link:

```
    public_path('storage/profilephotos') => storage_path('app/public/profilephotos')
```

When uploading an image I did this:

```
     Storage::put('profilephotos', $theimagefile);
```

This uploaded the image to the following directory:

```
      c:\myproject\storage\app\profilephotos\
```

The name of the file is for example 12345.jpg.
Now I want to view the iamge on a web apge. In blade I tried to add this but it doesn't work:

```
      asset('storage/profilephotos/12345.jpg')
```

I've already run storage:link which said:

```
      The [C:\myproject\public\storage] link has been connected to [C:\myproject\storage\app/public].
```

I don't know what else to do, can someone help?

thanks

Comment: When you upload it, you need to add public on the storage bucket option when put, so `Storage::disk('public')->put("profilephotos", $theimagefile);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as follows:

Create the basic symlink. Don't worry about sub-directories:

```
'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

Now run the command:

```
 php artisan storage:link
```

This creates an "app\public" folder in "\storage", and creates a linked folder "storage" in the "\public" folder ( like a shortcut,
"\public\storage" points to "\storage\app\public" )

To upload a file to this folder, simply PUT the file in to the '\storage\app\public' folder like this:

```
 Storage::put('public/', $someimagefileuploaded);  //(automatically uses the "hashName" of the uploaded image)
 Storage::put('public/subfolders-also-work/', $someimagefileuploaded);
```

You can also delete from this storage area too:

```
 Storage::delete('public/'.$oldimagefileuploaded);
```

To view an image in this storage folder via Blade, use the following code:

```
 <img src='{{ asset('storage/some-image-here.jpg') }}' />
 <img src='{{ asset('storage/subfolders-also-work/some-image-here.jpg') }}' />
```

In the above case, "asset('storage/...." knows to look for an asset in the "/storage/app/public" folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think if your code is correct to upload image,then you are using linux based operating system,ubuntu,parrotos,kali-linux etc. may be permission issue, correct the permission of the folder /storage, set min 755.
And also set user of the project folder www-data  or at least  /storage folder.

Laravel basic code to upload image

```
if ($request->hasFile('image_name')) {
    $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image_name->extension();
    $doctor->image_name=  $imageName;
    $request->image_name->storeAs('profilephotos', $imageName,'public');
}
```

Image store at /storage/profilephotos/image_name.png ,you can access image after creating the softlink as

```
 <img src="{{asset('/storage/profilephotos/image_name.png')}}"  alt="">
```

And also first delete the already created softlink in /public folder, create again using command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Follow above step to upload and view image in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function image_save($images, $folderName, $name)
    {
        if ($images) {
            // Set the path where images will be saved
            $path = public_path('images/' . $folderName);

            // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
            if (!file_exists($path)) {

                mkdir($path, 0777, true);
            }
            $imageName = 'XX' . '_' . $name . '.' . $images->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $images->move($path, $imageName);
        }
        return $imageName;
    }
```

This May Help..

Comment: thanks. I figured out the problem, will post the solution I found

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).